# warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to solve this warning or how to solve this issue

> ROMANCHs-MacBook-Pro:depot romanch$ rake db:migrate
>
> /Users/romanch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777

ruby version is 2.2.2 and rails version is 4.2.3

also getting this error on rails command

> ROMANCHs-MacBook-Pro:depot romanch$ rails -v
>
> /Users/romanch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
>   /Users/romanch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/bundler-1.10.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:78: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
>
> Rails 4.2.3

Comment: What is in your PATH in your shell?

Comment: ROMANCHs-MacBook-Pro:depot romanch$ this is the path in my shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To eliminate this particular error, just execute

```
sudo chmod 755 /usr
```

But in general, world-writable `/usr` directory means there are problems in your system.

Comment: Thank you this solves my problem but what do you mean by problems in my system in world-writable  /usr . what is that problem

Comment: Some software/human has changed the access rights to the system directory, making the whole system vulnerable to attacks.